# Uncaught TypeError: this.canvas is undefined

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dom, canvas, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create an instance of the Object class but i get this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: this.canvas is undefined**

I'm quite new to javascript, so I might have made a few silly mistakes.

Here is the code and the folder structure:

```
projectname/
- index.html
- index.js
- js/
-- Object.js
```

file: *index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

file: *index.js*

```
import { Object } from "/js/Object.js";

var obj = new Object();
obj.position = (500, 500, 0);
```

file: */js/Object.js*

```
export class Object {

    constructor() {
        this.position = new Array(0, 0, 0);
        this.velocity = new Array(0, 0, 0);
        this.force = new Array(0, 0, 0);
        this.mass = 0;

        this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    }

    get position() {
        return this._position;
    }

    set position(n_position) {
        this._position = n_position;
        this.canvas.style.left = n_position[0].toString()+"px";
        this.canvas.style.top = n_position[1].toString()+"px";
    }
}
```

Comment: [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object) is a predefined variable in JS. Naming your class Object is, at best, very confusing (at worst it might be the case of your problem).

Comment: `obj.position = (500, 500, 0);` is the same as `obj.position = 0`. Array syntax uses `[]` not `()`.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your constructor you have:

> ```
> this.position = new Array(0, 0, 0);
> ```

which calls the setter function which tries to read `this.canvas` **before** you have:

> ```
> this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
> ```

which creates the canvas that you tried to modify five lines earlier.

---

Order matters. Create your canvas before you try to modify it.

Comment: Just moved the `this.canvas = ...` at the beginning of the constructor and now it works perfectly! Thank you!